# CSS Form, ASP.NET Validation Summary is Wonky

Tags: asp.net, css, validationsummary

Ok, this is driving me insane.

I have a form and I'm not using tables. Each row is a p tag and consists of a label and a control. When I add a validation summary at the bottom it goes wonky.

How do I get the validation summary to line up properly?

```
.Label
{
    float: left;
    width: 12em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.TextBox
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 244px;
}

<p>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="uxNotesLabel" CssClass="Label">Notes</>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="uxNotesTextBox" CssClass="TextBox" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
</p>

<p>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="uxSpaceLabel3" CssClass="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="uxMaterialNeedValidationSummary" ValidationGroup="AddMaterialNeed" ForeColor="Red" />
</p>
```

That gives me this:

[image: PatienceTester]

Comment: This may sound silly, but did try adding a class to the validation summary and apply styles to it? And what is it that you want to line up? The text to be centered or do you want the box aligned to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not too clear:

Would you need CSS like:

```
#uxMaterialNeedValidationSummary {text-align:center;}
```

or

```
#uxMaterialNeedValidationSummary {padding-left:12em;}
```

Whatever id or class is avalaible

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus I can use the padding to align the summary how I like.